# If $m \equiv n \pmod{A}$, then $s^m \equiv s^n \pmod{A}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm kind of stuck with the following assignment:

> Prove: If $m \equiv n \pmod{A}$, then $s^m \equiv s^n \pmod{A}$

I tried $m = k_1 \times A + r$ , 
and $n = k_2 \times A + r$ ,
then $s^m = s^{k_1 \times A + r}$,
but not sure how to proceed ...

Really appreciate any hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zev thanks for editing the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is false as stated - consider $A=3$, $m=4$, $n=1$, and $s=2$. We have $$4\equiv 1\bmod 3$$ but $$16\not\equiv 2\bmod 3.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there anyway to prove this beside plugging-in the number?

Comment: @user350954 Disproving such statements is easiest to do using examples. There are, in fact, some $m,n,A$ such that the above is true for all $s$, they are just rare

Comment: I see, thanks a lot, guys

Answer (score 3):

It is not true like that.

You probably meant ($\gcd(A,s)=1$ and $m\equiv n\pmod{\varphi(A)}$) implies $s^m\equiv s^n\pmod{A}$, where $\varphi$ is *Euler's totient function*, i.e. $\varphi(A)$ is the number of coprimes to $A$ (within one total residue class).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Berci, but it's too advanced for me ...